Bonjour (mdnsNSP.dll) from iTunes blocked from loading into Local Security Authority for no apparent reason
Recently, my Windows 11 starts to show the window below after boot. Now my iTunes would not detect Apple devices when they're plugged in. Does anyone know how to resolve this compatibility issue?


Do you have the desktop or UWP version of iTunes installed?

@Ramhound Initially I installed the App from the Microsoft Store. Once I started getting this error, I uninstalled the MS Store App and installed the 64-bit executable from iTunes official website to troubleshoot. But the error continued to persist.

Is your machine connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Try pulling out the update Bonjur.zip the file that’s blocked is from 2010

@Ramhound I've uninstalled Bonjour but the problem persists

My suggestion was to replace the file with an updated version of the file not uninstall Bonjour

@Ramhound I ran the installer for Bonjour 3.1.0.1, but "Error occurred" every time it ran

So you extracted the file out of the installer, which is just a compressed archive, and replaced the file that was installed with the one from 3.1.0.1?

Go to Control Panel, then Programs, then Programs and Features.  Look for Bonjour on the list, Right Mouse Click on it. Select Repair.  Reboot PC and the Program Compatibility Assistant blocking it should be gone.
Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Right Mouse Click on Bonjour (on the list) and choose Repair.

